# Simple Renderscript Example failing

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I am trying to create an image processing library, built in renderscript.  I have been playing with the [android samples](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/java/tests/) for Renderscript here.

Renderscript appears to have everything I need to create this library, unfortunately I cannot seem to get many of the examples to work for me.

The ImageProcecssing example is a good example of how things tend to work for me.  Most of the Script Intrinsics work out of the box, no errors.  However, as soon as I move to a ScriptC file, even doing *basic* thngs tends to fail.  And by fail, I mean

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 21581 (enderscripttest)
```

So, to help debug, I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/jamieomatthews/renderscript-test) with literally the most basic example I could come up with.  It basically just attempts to apply a brightness filter to an imageview.

Relevant code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inSampleSize = 8;
        originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.colors,opts);
        filteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(),originalBitmap.getHeight(), originalBitmap.getConfig());

        //RENDERSCRIPT ALLOCATION
        mRS = RenderScript.create(this);
        mInAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, originalBitmap,Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
        mOutAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, mInAllocation.getType());
        mOutAllocation.copyFrom(originalBitmap);
        mOutAllocation.copyTo(filteredBitmap);

        ScriptC_brightnessfilter helloworldScript = new ScriptC_brightnessfilter(mRS);

        helloworldScript.set_brightnessValue(4.0f);
        helloworldScript.bind_gPixels(mInAllocation);

        helloworldScript.set_gIn(mInAllocation);
        helloworldScript.set_gOut(mOutAllocation);
        helloworldScript.set_gScript(helloworldScript);
        helloworldScript.invoke_filter();
        mOutAllocation.copyTo(filteredBitmap);

    }
```

Then a renderscript file

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.dss.renderscripttest)

float brightnessValue;

rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript;

static int mImageWidth;
const uchar4 *gPixels;

void root(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar4 *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {

    float4 apixel = rsUnpackColor8888(*v_in);
    float3 pixel = apixel.rgb;
    float factor = brightnessValue;
    pixel = pixel + factor;
    pixel = clamp(pixel,0.0f,1.0f);
    *v_out = rsPackColorTo8888(pixel.rgb);
}


void filter() {
    mImageWidth = rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn);
    rsDebug("Image size is ", rsAllocationGetDimX(gIn), rsAllocationGetDimY(gOut));
    rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut, 0, 0);
}
```

I have only tested this on the Galaxy S3 and S4.  I will test on the Nexus 4 tonight and see if I get a different result.

Edit:

I have confirmed that this code **works** on the Nexus 4.  I will run through some other devices for good measure.  Also I will see if I can get an APK together in case Stephen Hines or Tim Murray wants to look, but right now it seems only Galaxy S3 and S4 (both 4.3) are effected

Edit 2: I believe this is the same issue that is happening [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647441/problems-with-the-renderscript-support-library).  I will update as both issues progress

Comment: Can you paste a logcat for the failing case? As mentioned on the other thread, there were a lot of missing symbols in the support library, so if this is the same problem, you will have to wait for a new SDK. Hopefully an SDK update will be out soon.

Comment: @StephenHines here is a gist I made https://gist.github.com/jamieomatthews/8324201.  The galaxy S3 & 4 are pretty bare, you get better errors out of the older devices that must be using the support lib

Comment: What Android versions are the S3/S4 running on? It looks like those are attempting to run native RenderScript and crashing. Is it JB-MR2 (4.3 or later)? I am concerned that Samsung may have broken something.

Comment: @StephenHines I just recently upgraded both phones to 4.3.  So yes, perhaps samsung has messed this up!